# Google Custom Search vs Google Site Search

Tags: google-custom-search

I have been using Google Custom Search programmatically to search and bring back information for me.  Since it is working well, I would like to get more searches per day.

Is Google Site Search the paid version of Google Custom Search, or can I pay for more searches using customer search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Google Site Search is the paid version of custom search and with more features. 
Here's some comparison for you - https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/4541888?hl=en

Access to XML API for results, no ads, on demand indexing and tech support are big plus with Google Site Search.